# Can't acess installed Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, usb

I am new to linux. I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a USB onto an Acer Aspire E15. I logged off and back into Windows 8.1. Now I can't figure out how to get back to Ubuntu. If I tell Windows to boot off the USB I used to install it originally, and try to reinstall it tells me there is already an instance of Ubuntu. I did some reading and used a temporary instance run off the usb to use boot repair. It seemed to run fine. Results here.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/15148829/
My computer still boots directly into the Windows password screen.

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get to my Linux install?
2. can I change things so that the computer boots into Linux first?

My boot menu looks like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lines 6 and 7 in the boot info script, are of importance:  => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (4.04 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb. How did you install Ubuntu? By choosing " Install alongside Windows" or "Something else"? It looks like there is no GRUB2 on your laptop, only on your USB stick.

Comment: You don't tell **Windows** to boot other systems. You tell the BIOS to do so. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI or in Legacy mode? Try switching boot priority from UEFI to Legacy and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for the quick rely. I found this tutorial.  http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/. It said to use the windows admin cmd shell and type in bcedit /set "{bootmgr}" path\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi. Now I get a menu that lets me boot into ubuntu AND into windows. They both seem to work fine. 

For installation I followed a "how to" and somehow lost it on my favorites. I can't recall which settings I chose at the time.

I take your point about telling the BIOS to boot other systems and not Windows. I will try to be more exact with my language, I know it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your GNU GRUB boot menu is not placed after the installation of Ubuntu. You can fix this by:

**Installing GRUB manually**

Insert your LiveUSB and select Try Ubuntu.
Run GParted (Search for it in the Dash menu)
Determine your correct hard drive (where you boot your OSes out of). You can select other hard drives at the upper right of the window.
if you have found the correct hard drive, write down what's shown at the top right of the window. (EG /dev/sda).
Now open up the Terminal (CTRL+ALT+T)
Type in:
sudo grub-install /PATH/TOHDD
This will install the GRUB boot menu loader into the MBR of the first IDE disk (meaning that the GRUB menu will show when you start your pc).
After this operation is done, reboot your system and remove the USB. If you are sent to Ubuntu, you're good to go.

Source: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Installing-GRUB-using-grub_002dinstall.html

Comment: if correctly installed, GRUB will show you other OSes to pick from after rebooting Ubuntu once.

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. You guys are awesome. I have been days trying to get this to work.

Comment: I am trying to mark this question as answered but I don't know if I am able to do that. I am satisfied with the answers, and consider this closed.